# How to use phone number instead of email in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I'm a beginner Rails developer. Devise is a gem based on email. In my project, I don't have email, I only have phone number. So on the method `sign_in` and `sign_up` I need to use phone instead of email.

The problem is I can't register a new user if I don't set an email.

Of course, I can do something like this:

```
user.email = '+77777779999@gmail.com'
```

But it's not really a good solution for me.

What can I do?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model

```
attr_accessible :authentication_keys => [:phone_number]
```

and in your `project-name/config/initializers/devise.rb` set your `authentication_keys`:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :phone_number ]
```